# Simple MVC route does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've created a new MVC project. I've created an empty controller called APIController:

```
public class APIController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I've created the corresponding views, which are empty apart from the word 'index' and 'test'.

When I go to `myurl.com/Account` it works

When I go to `myurl.com/Account/Test` I get an xml error saying:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI [...]
>
> No type was found that matches the controller named 'Account'.

This must be a noob error. Everything else in the project is default. The RegisterRoutes method is the default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

What silly thing am I missing?

Bonus points if you can explain why the error is an XML error and not the standard yellow screen of death...

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?  I've followed your steps, for MVC 3 and 4, exactly, without error.

Comment: MVC 4. I'll post exact code even though it's all basic defaults

Comment: Is that `APIController` a typo there?  Did you mean `AccountController`?

Comment: I've solved it, I didn't realise the name was important I just used a generic name for the question!

Comment: Thanks guys. I wonder who made that genius decision...

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

Turns out if you call your controller APIController MVC treats it completely differently. Renaming it to ABCController worked great.

I'm not writing an API, I'm writing a website that manages an API!

Argh, thanks MVC!

Comment: +1 That's interesting, that must be like some hidden usage of a standard Controller before they introduced the `ApiController`.

Comment: @James I'm certain it does this for other types, too.  I'm sure I've run into something similar to this in the past.

Comment: Come to think of it, Since there's an ApiController class, calling your controller APIController probably isn't the smartest thing anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the controller you created is inheriting `ApiController` instead of the standard  `Controller`?

This would also explain why the error message is being returned in XML.

Comment: I am inheriting Controller as I am building a website rather than API. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what you would inherit for a website. But based on this URL: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12001/no-http-resource-was-found-that-matches-the-request-uri-in-m.aspx you would get XML if inheriting from the ApiController. Very similar to the problem you described.

Comment: If you would inherit from the ApiController, you wouldn't be able to do `return View()` i.e. the code doesn't even compile